# How to search Xcode4.2 project?

Tags: xcode, search, xcode4, project, xcode4.2

I'd like to run a search on all files in my project. How can this be done in Xcode please?

Comment: Press Cmd + 3 to show the Search Navigator.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In Xcode 4, as Jano mentioned:

- `⌘3` (Command + 3) will show the Search Navigator

However:

- `⇧⌘F` (Command + Shift + F) will open the Search Navigator with focus on the search field

Both of these keyboard shortcuts will bring open the panel you need to search in all files. [This page on developer.apple.com](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/IDEs/Conceptual/xcode_help-command_shortcuts/MenuCommands/MenuCommands014.html) shows a list of the keyboard shortcuts available in Xcode.

From that reference, the following are the other Find related shortcuts:

```
Find in Workspace…             ⇧⌘F  (Shift-Command-F)
Find and Replace in Workspace… ⌥⇧⌘F (Option-Shift-Command-F)
Find…                          ⌘F   (Command-F)
Find and Replace…              ⌥⌘F  (Option-Command-F)
Find Next                      ⌘G   (Command-G)
Find Previous                  ⇧⌘G  (Shift-Command-G)
Use Selection for Find         ⌘E   (Command-E)
Use Selection for Replace      ⇧⌘E  (Shift-Command-E)
```